# Which method has the highest yield of calcium sulfate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, titration

I'm not sure which of following two methods will give better yields for $\ce{CaSO4}$:

A. Add dilute $\ce{HNO3}$ to $\ce{CaCO3}$, followed by dilute $\ce{H2SO4}$; or

B. Titrate aqeuous calcium hydroxide with dilute sulfuric acid.

I'm leaning towards Method B since it is easier to point out when the reaction is complete, and the yield would thus be close to 100%.

For Method A, however, any excess $\ce{CaCO3}$ would react with $\ce{H2SO4}$ and any excess $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}$ might undergo a displacement reaction where $\ce{NO3-}$ ions are displaced by $\ce{SO4^2-}$.

Comment: A if yield is based on precipitation (compare calcium sulphate and hydroxide solubilities), B if on evaporation.

Comment: Consider that in A. you add an extra species that is *not* needed in the end, and in B., the only product besides gypsum is water.

Comment: Are you going to evaporate the leftover solution?